# Programming Documentation

Tags: java, file, path

I have always had problems reading documentation for example
I was just researching about file paths for java and I so this :
"
 Usage Example:

```
Path file = ...
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

"
//http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html

What is ..... ??? :|
I know im not a expert but example code that is full coded would be nice, Or Is is it becouse im not at that 
level yet...

I tried testing it..did not even run :(

Please Help

Comment: ... means fill the blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API documentation is meant to give you details about a particular class and serve as a reference to come back to. It's purpose is not to provide you with an explanation how concepts fit together. So `...` stands as a placeholder for any code that might make sense in a particular use case. For a general overview Oracle hosts an excellent set of [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

And if you want to see even a bigger picture, I can recommend an excellent book [Thinking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486).

Answer (score 0):

The ... is called an *ellipsis*, and means that something has been left out there.  On this case, it's a call to the Path constructor, putting a path in place ready for the rest of the code.

They do that because they don't want to clutter the example with extraneous stuff.

If you want fully coded examples, the Java Almanac has good ones, albeit a little dated.

[http://www.amazon.com/The-Java%C2%BF-Developers-Almanac-Volume/dp/0201752808](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752808)